# hooks versus middleware in slim 2.0

Tags: slim

Can anyone explain if there are any significant advantages or disadvantages when choosing to implement features such as authentication or caching etc using hooks as opposed to using middleware?
For instance - I can implement a translation feature by obtaining the request object through custom middleware and setting an app language variable that can be used to load the correct translation file when the app executes. Or I can add a hook before the routing and read the request variable and then load the correct file during the app execution.
Is there any obvious reason I am missing that makes one choice better than the other?

Answer (score 6):

**Super TL/DR; (The very short answer)**

Use middleware when first starting some aspect of your application, i.e. routers, the boot process, during login confirmation, and use hooks everywhere else, i.e. in components or in microservices.

**TL/DR; (The short answer)**

*Middleware* is used when the order of execution matters. Because of this, middleware is often added to the execution stack in various aspects of code (middleware is often added during boot, while adding a logger, auth, etc. In most implementations, each middleware function subsequently decides if execution is continued or not.

However, using middleware when order of execution does *not* matter tends to lead to bugs in which middleware that gets added does not continue execution by mistake, or the intended order is shuffled, or someone simply forgets where or why a middleware was added, because it can be added almost anywhere. These bugs can be difficult to track down.

*Hooks* are generally not aware of the execution order; each hooked function is simply executed, and that is all that is guaranteed (i.e. adding a hook after another hook does not guarantee the 2nd hook is always executed second, only that it will simply be executed). The choice to perform it's task is left up to the function itself (to call out to state to halt execution). Most people feel this is much simpler and has fewer moving parts, so statistically yields less bugs. However, to detect if it should run or not, it can be important to include additional state in hooks, so that the hook does not reach out into the app and couple itself with things it's not inherently concerned with (this can take discipline to reason well, but is usually simpler). Also, because of their simplicity, hooks tend to be added at certain named points of code, yielding fewer areas where hooks can exist (often a single place).

Generally, hooks are easier to reason with and store because their order is not guaranteed or thought about. Because hooks can negate themselves, hooks are also computationally equivalent, making middleware only a form of coding style or shorthand for common issues.

**Deep dive**

Middleware is generally thought of today by architects as a poor choice. Middleware can lead to nightmares and the added effort in debugging is rarely outweighed by any shorthand achieved.

Middleware and Hooks (along with Mixins, Layered-config, Policy, Aspects and more) are all part of the "strategy" type of [design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Strategy patterns, because they are invoked whenever code branching is involved, are probably one of if not the most often used software design patterns.

Knowledge and use of strategy patterns are probably the easiest way to detect the skill level of a developer.

A strategy pattern is used whenever you need to apply "if...then" type of logic (optional execution/branching).

The more computational thought experiments that are made on a piece of software, the more branches can mentally be reduced, and subsequently refactored away. This is essentially "aspect algebra"; constructing the "bones" of the issue, or thinking through what is happening over and over, reducing the procedure to it's fundamental concepts/first principles. When refactoring, these thought experiments are where an architect spends the most time; finding common aspects and reducing unnecessary complexity.

At the destination of complexity reduction is [emergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergence) (in systems theory vernacular, and specifically with software, applying configuration in special layers instead of writing software in the first place) and [monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)).

Monads tend to abstract away what is being done to a level that can lead to increased code execution time if a developer is not careful.

Both Monads and Emergence tend to abstract the problem away so that the parts can be universally applied using fundamental building blocks. Using Monads (for the small) and Emergence (for the large), any piece of complex software can be theoretically constructed from the least amount of parts possible.

After all, in refactoring: "the easiest code to maintain is code that no longer exists."

**Functors and mapping functions**

A great way to continually reduce complexity is applying functors and mapping functions. Functors are also usually the fastest possible way to implement a branch and let the compiler see into the problem deeply so it can optimize things in the best way possible. They are also extremely easy to reason with and maintain, so there is rarely harm in leaving your work for the day and committing your changes with a partially refactored application.

Functors get their name from mathematics (specifically category theory, in which they are referred to a function that maps between two sets). However, in computation, functors are generally just objects that map problem-space in one way or another.

There is great debate over what is or is not a functor in computer science, but in keeping with the definition, you only need to be concerned with the act of mapping out your problem, and using the "functor" as a temporary thought scaffold that allows you to abstract the issue away until it becomes configuration or a factor of implementation instead of code.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can say that `middleware` is perfect for each routing work. And `hooks` is best for doing anything application-wide. For your case I think it should be better to use `hooks` than middleware.

Comment: Thank for the reply, can you expand on why middleware is better for route specific operations? I thought that route middleware was for route specific processes and app middleware is for application-wide operations? The only thing I can see that is of any real difference is that hooks can be triggered at specific points in the dispatch process, but it seems to me that the "before" hook is exactly the same as the app middleware feature.